# Spring Security Java Configuration IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I need to turn the XML configuration into java how can I do for this part please

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST"
        ref="metadataGeneratorFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"
        ref="samlFilter" />
</security:http>
```

I tried this but i got some error

.anyRequest().access("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY");

Failed to evaluate expression IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use
`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated()`

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide an explanation to your answer.

Comment: @MickaëlB This code is self-explanatory. There is no need to explain here anything. This is just a translation of XML into java :)

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide any information about why he gets an error in the first place and why your answer will solve his problem. So I don't think it's *"self-explanatory"*...

Comment: I tried but it does not work because in AuthenticatedVoter  [ org.springframework.security.access.vote ] the class use IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY